# Which are the most popular phone processors?

Tags: processor, mobile-phone

For my scientific research I need to know the most popular phone processors to know their FLOPS parameters. But I can't find a some resource about it. I could find the best mobile processors only (but I need the average parameters, not the best).
**Does anyone know sites or some another ways where to get a list of the most popular phone processors?**

Comment: This is off-topic for our site, as we provide recommendations based on specific requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at this: https://deviceatlas.com/blog/most-popular-smartphones

It gives the 12 most popular phones by country.

Comment: Thank you very much! It will help to find processors.